# UIKeyboard next button not going to next UITextField

Tags: ios, uikeyboard, resignfirstresponder, becomefirstresponder

I have been trying to figure out how to get the next button on the UIKeyboard to load the next UITextField.. I have two cells, Name and Email I would like to go from Name to Email using the Next button.

so far I have added

```
//.h
 <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

then I am doing this to try and pass the user from Name to Email

```
//.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    customerNameTextField.delegate = self;
    customerEmailTextField.delegate = self;
//...

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (![customerNameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [customerNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [customerEmailTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == customerEmailTextField) {
        // here you can define what happens
        // when user presses return on the email field
        // send request
    }
    return YES;
}
```

It enters the first if statment, then It removes the keyboard from the screen using resignFirstResponder but then it dose not load the new keyboard using becomeFirstResponder.. Any help fixing this would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: Sure that customerEmailTextField is not nil?

Comment: I have to change the second part of the if statment.. but im not quite sure what you are refering too?

Comment: If customerEmailTextField is nil your code [customerEmailTextField becomeFirstResponder] wouldn't work obviously...

Comment: I don't think you need to resignfirstresponder if your telling the next field to becomefirstresponder. Also, I think you should be returning NO.

Comment: I hope this isnt too much of a stupid question but how do I stop it from being nil?.. okay just read your suggestion.. I am going to try now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will go from one textfield to next textField...

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == ist) {
        [second becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == second) {
        [third becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This worked once I changed the return YES to return NO... not sure why... but just letting everyone know.